# Getting the navigation properties of an inherited entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

For the purpose of an auditing system, I need to be able to retrieve the navigation properties of an entity through the ChangeTracker/ObjectStateManager before the entity is saved. With the navigation properties retrieved, I would loop through each one and save its name, type and primary key.

I am using the following code to do that:

```
var context = new SomeDbContext();
var entity = context.SomeEntities.Find(1);

entity.MakeSomeChanges();
entity.MakeMoreChanges();

context.ObjectContext.DetectChanges();

var stateManager = context.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
var stateEntry = stateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity);
var entityType = stateEntry.EntitySet.ElementType as EntityType;

// from here I can work with the navigation properties.
foreach (var property in entityType.NavigationProperties)
{
    // process nav property
}
```

This approach works great for basic entities, however the problem I am having is trying to find the navigation properties on an entity that inheritied from a base entity. For example, given the following structure:

```
public class ParentEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ChildEntity : ParentEntity
{
    public int NavigationEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual NavigationEntity NavigationEntity { get; set; }
}

public class NavigationEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildEntity> ChildEntities { get; set; }
}
```

How would I be able to find the navigation properties on ChildEntity? If I use the same approach above like with SomeEntity, this is what happens:

```
var context = new SomeDbContext();
var navEntity = context.NavigationEntities.Find(1);
var childEntity = new ChildEntity();

navEntity.ChildEntities.Add(childEntity);

context.ObjectContext.DetectChanges();

var stateManager = context.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
var stateEntry = stateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(childEntity);

// entityType here turns into ParentEntity, which does not have nav properties
var entityType = stateEntry.EntitySet.ElementType as EntityType;
var properties = entityType.NavigationProperties;

// properties.Count() == 0
```

Is there some way I could convert ParentEntity into ChildEntity?
Or perhaps there is a different approach I could take to retrieve the navigation properties of an entity in the change tracker?

Comment: Is it worth investigating `entityType.DeclaredNavigationProperties`? cant see what they are or how to use them tho, so may not be useful to you.

Comment: Perhaps, I will give it a shot. Edit: Unfortunately it was not useful because entityType is still ParentEntity and the Edm thinks that it does not have any declared nav properties. @Rhumborl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you go back to the `EntitySet` of the sub type you're interested in. But the `EntitySet` is defined on the base type: you get `ChildEntity`s by...

```
db.ParentEntities.OfType<ChildEntity>()
```

So you have to get the navigation properties in a different way. I've used this little function for that purpose:

```
IEnumerable<NavigationProperty> GetNavigationProperies<T>(DbContext context,
                                                          T entity = default(T))
    where T : class
{
    var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    var entityType = oc.MetadataWorkspace
                       .GetItems(DataSpace.OSpace).OfType<EntityType>()
                       .FirstOrDefault (et => et.Name == typeof(T).Name);
    return entityType != null
        ? entityType.NavigationProperties
        : Enumerable.Empty<NavigationProperty>();
}
```

You can either call this without a concrete object and the generic type parameter specified...

```
var navprops = GetNavigationProperies<ChildEntity>(db);
```

or with an object and relying on type inference...

```
var navprops = GetNavigationProperies(db, childEntity);
```